# "Educational review articles": How find these

Tags: publications, review-articles

Every once in a while I come across some really well-written review articles. They do not review a field of study and provide insane amounts of references to previous work; rather, they review a narrow topic, an experimental method, or a concept, in a way such that simple-minded MSc students - like myself - can understand the topic. Basically, they have written a sub-section in a textbook, but on a topic where the theory has yet to make it to a textbook.

One of these articles, Berera et al. (2009), categorized their paper as an "educational review". This is a genre I would pay to read more of, but I just stumble upon these every once in a while. It seems the term "educational review" is not a very common term for such reviews, and I always end up in journals reviewing methods in lower/higher educational.

So I ask here whether anyone know how to locate these educational reviews that I look for, or whether there is another term I can use more efficiently. I would really appreciate some assistance. My field of interest is anything chemistry-related.

Berera, van Grondelle, and Kennis (2009). *Ultrafast transient absorption spectroscopy: principles and application to photosynthetic systems*. Photosynthesis Research 101(2-3): 105-118.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen them called 'tutorial reviews'. Since you say you're in chemistry, see for example Chem Soc Rev's tutorial reviews, as they call them here:

http://www.rsc.org/journals-books-databases/about-journals/chem-soc-rev/

Here's an extract from how they define 'tutorial review':

> Tutorial reviews are concise, authoritative overviews of important contemporary topics in the chemical sciences. They should appeal to advanced undergraduates, the general research chemist who is new to the field, as well as the expert. They provide a solid introduction to the development of a subject, the latest breakthrough results and their implications for the wider scientific community.
>
> Accessible: To advanced undergraduate students and beyond. Tutorial reviews are often used in advanced undergraduate and Master’s studies.
>
> Authoritative: An essential introduction to the field will lay the foundation of knowledge in the area with approximately 25 seminal citations, serving as a springboard to further reading, followed by the most important recent advances.
>
> Jargon free: Specialist terms and symbols should be defined and fundamental ideas simply explained.

I guess that's what you're thinking of?